# How to update bios with windows exe file

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, bios, battery

I try to update my bios with a file which I downloaded from official Lenovo website.Finding  update file is super easy but because of my battery doesn't charge anymore I could not update bios on Windows.

I created a bootable DOS USB disk by using a program called Rufus and I created a folder which I named BIOS and then copied the file into this folder and copied the folder into USB and boot the computer from USB but when I write the name of the  update-file I downloaded  on prompt command it says  " this program must run under win32"..So I learned there are two types of exe-file:for DOS and for Windows.Lenovo provide only windows version.

I tried update my bios because I have fan and overheating problem and Lenovo says updating bios is likely to solve this problem.

---

My battery says ( 0%  and it is not charging ) so I tried to make it work again by following a video I watched on youtube.

I tried to uninstall Windows battery drivers on Device manager but when I reboot the computer two files which I uninstalled installed again automatically.So I cannot uninstall them.

And I cannot reach bios screen on my computer. I only get into a screen when I push f2 at start-up where I can only change boot priority.

Comment: So what exactly is your question, I see at least, three separate problems you might need help with.

Comment: Is 0% battery preventing you from upgrading your BIOS from Windows?

Comment: Lenovo generally use F1 for setup, F12 for boot menu

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for my MSI motherboard. I moved .exe file to USB flash drive and run the file while in windows, when the setup is done after you wait for a minute, it will say to not remove your flash drive and then it automatically reboots, after that you will see on screen BIOS updating progress. Done.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But the Op cant get into windows